# I am having trouble with getline() function in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, getline

Hello I am having trouble with the getline() function in C++ I am new to C++ and relatively new to programming period. I am in an intro to C++ course and my research that I have done on this topic myself online has not led me to a solution I do not really understand all the things that they speak about as this is the very first assignment in my class. Any quick/rough help/understanding would be greatly appreciated as we will cover this topic in class more thoroughly. Below is the code that I am writing. It is a simple program that just asks users for name and address and then displays that info in correct mailing format.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
 // Variables for Mailing Addresses
  std::string firstName;
  std::string lastName;
  int houseNum;
  std::string streetName;
  std::string cityName;
  std::string state;
  int zipCode;

 // Asking for input
  std::cout << "What is your First name?: ";
  std::cin >> firstName;"\n";

  std::cout << "What is your Last name?: ";
  std::cin >> lastName;"\n";

  std::cout << "What is your House Number?: ";
  std::cin >> houseNum;"\n";

  std::cout << "What is your Street Name?: ";
  std::getline(std::cin,houseNum);
 return 0;
}
```

The error code thats thrown is "No matching function for call to 'getline'".

Comment: `std::getline(std::cin,houseNum);` shoud be: `std::getline(std::cin, streetName);`

Comment: Why do you use `std::cin` for the first three and `std::getline` for the last? What made you want to do something different there? What does your input actually look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `getline()` is that you are trying to assign a string stream to an `int` variable `houseNum`, hence the error.

> no matching function for call to 'getline(**std::istream&, int&**)'

Also, the line of code:

```
std::cin >> firstName;"\n";
```

Should give you:

> warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]

For the `"\n"`

Enable [**compiler warnings**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), they save you a lot of time.

Comment: @JohnDellaVecchio, glad to help, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see a couple major issues.

You have this line:

```
std::cin >> firstName;"\n";
```

The first part is correct, but the second part is not.
You want this:

```
std::cin >> firstName;
std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
```

Also, you call `getline` on the string objects you created earlier. `std::cin` is a stream-type object, not a string. I suggest you look at [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) that talks about `getline`.